# plugins required for code coverage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was looking for the eclipse plugin for the purpose of code coverage which has some features like that it can catch the duplicate piece of code in mine class and it can alert mine for any null checks that I have miss , the null checks are important , it should alert me wherever I have miss and additionally it should check my several if else conditions also since I am using most if else conditions so it can alert me in advance where the extra if condition I have put that was not require, Please advise the plugin with these functionalists for eclipse.

Comment: Google "code review eclipse" to get a list of Eclipse tools, some free others not, that check for the kinds of conditions you've listed. I don't have any first-hand knowledge of these tools, so I'm just adding a comment and not an answer.

Comment: folks please advise for this plugin

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/). The analyses arebased on all famous plugin like PMD, Checkstyle, FindBugs, etc.

To be alert directly in Eclipse, there is a plugin: [Eclipse sonar plugin](http://www.sonarsource.org/eclipse-sonar-plugin-0-1-in-screenshots/).

Maybe a screenshot ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Code coverage -- how well the tests cover the code

http://ecobertura.johoop.de/

http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2012/01/cobertura-and-eclipse-ecobertura.html

What you are asking for is Findbugs ([Demo](http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/demo/jdk7/index.html))

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html

Sample Message:

> Method invokes inefficient Number constructor; use static valueOf instead   (3)